# Can I use assets from the Unity store in a non Unity project I host publicly?

Tags: unity, legal

I'm working on a simple game for university that I'm making using HTML and Javascript (not Unity) that I'd like to be able to put up on a public github repo and/or maybe host online somewhere. I'd like to use some free assets from the unity store on it.

I've read [Can free Unity Store assets be used in non-Unity games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129767/can-free-unity-store-assets-be-used-in-non-unity-games/129922) so using Unity Assets is probably alright but if I store my project on a public github repo, anyone would be able to access those assets from there and not need to use the Unity Store for those specific ones.

To quote the linked page, "The only catch appears to be that you must download the assets through Unity, and that you are purchasing a license for the asset."

Also, if it's okay to store Unity Store Assets in a public repo, how should I do it? Just put each asset within a separate folder with a text file containing its license?

Edit: I found this in the Unity Asset Store Terms of Service:

```
Unless you have been specifically permitted to do so in a separate
agreement with Unity and except as permitted under the Unity-EULA,
you agree that you will not reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, trade
or resell any Asset that you have acquired from the Unity Asset Store
for any purpose.
```

So, is that a definite no to what I'd like to do?

Comment: Seems pretty self explanatory. If you can't redistribute the assets, you can't make them publicly available through your github. That would be redistributing the assets. Ultimately, anything else would be nothing more than a possible argument, if you get sued.

Comment: Would it be okay to host the assets on a private server and 'compile' them in some manner before sending them clientside? Not going to do it to err on the side of caution, but just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be legal.

From here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/342714/use-of-asset-store-assests-in-commercial-game.html

> You can NOT re-distribute the file, no matter how much you modify it you can use it but not share or re-sell it.

and based on

> Unless you have been specifically permitted to do so in a separate
>   agreement with Unity and except as permitted under the Unity-EULA,
>   you agree that you will not reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, trade
>   or resell any Asset that you have acquired from the Unity Asset Store
>   for any purpose.

from the terms of service which I quoted above, I'm fairly certain hosting any assets in a public repository would not be legal.